# Docker run: how to run Ubuntu:16.04 without command?

Tags: docker

I want to try out installing a program inside of Ubuntu in docker,

So I just run directly from the command prompt

```
docker run --name ubuntu_test ubuntu:16.04
docker exec -it ubuntu_test bash
```

but it doesn't work, it says container not running? how can I run the bash without setting up a dockerfile? (I tried using dockerfile, but it doesn't work because of [interactive installer problem](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/5978/dockerfile-how-can-i-input-an-enter-when-in-interactive-sh-installer))

So I thought maybe directly install it from the bash could work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your command doesn't keep the proccess alive nor does it keep it in the background so the container finishes its work and stops running. Its like `docker run hello-world` which prints some stuff and exits.

`docker run -it --name ubuntu_test ubuntu:16.04` will work for you. The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) explains:

`For interactive processes (like a shell), you must use -i -t together in order to allocate a tty for the container process. -i -t is often written -it`

An alternative would be to run the container in detached mode (-d) and give it a long running command so that it doesn't exit immediately:

`docker run --name ubuntu_test -d ubuntu:16.04 sleep 300
docker exec -it ubuntu_test bash`

Answer (score 7):

You are failing to start the container. Try this:

```
docker run -itd ubuntu:16.04 bash
```

> -i, --interactive - Keep STDIN open even if not attached
>
> -t, --tty - Allocate a pseudo-TTY
>
> -d,  --detach - Run container in background and print container ID

After this command list all your containers(`docker ps`):

[image]

Now you can attach to your running container and do some stuff:

```
docker exec -it 82d0bb7754e7 /bin/bash
```

(in this case, to indicate the container I used the ID, you can also use container name)

Answer (score 1):

This should be work:

```
docker run --rm -it --name ubuntu_test -d ubuntu:16.04 
docker exec -it ubuntu_test /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run a container you can pass a command at the end of the command that should run, like:

```
docker run --name ubuntu_test -it ubuntu:16.04 bash
```

If there's an Entrypoint specified in Dockerfile then you need to override entrypoint:

```
docker run --name ubuntu_test -it --entrypoint bash ubuntu:16.04
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, you are on right way with installing into running image. It is not convenient because not automated - next time you need your image you will have to do all steps again and there is no way to record them.

I would suggest instead to try to fix the interactive installer problem, you are not the first one to face it. There are many ways, including `yes` program, which automatically outputs predefined answer to the installer's questions or you can simply use `echo` piping the result to installer.